# How to round border in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

How to round border in blender
[image]

No matter what I did, I could not round the edge of my object

Comment: Try a bevel: Select the edge and Ctrl B? If you've used a Solidify modifier you need to bevel the vertex instead (press V after Ctrl B)

Comment: (ctrl b) only rounds the object but does not round the border

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a *Solidify Modifier*, make sure you *Apply* it first or right click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Mesh*.

1.) Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*
2.) Press <kbd>2</kbd> for *Edge Select* mode
3.) Select the edge you want to bevel
4.) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel and scroll mouse up to add segments
5.) Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> to apply the bevel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you send this to me?

Comment: Just an observation: It looks as if the Scale hasn't been applied on the object in that answer as you can see that the bevel isn't symmetrical. In Object mode, CTRL-A > Scale should sort that.

Comment: @JohnEason it's only the default cube, i didn't scale it. it's an illusion because of the perspective :)

Comment: Really? In that case, my apologies! :^)